# C++ issue with bubble sort

Tags: c++, sorting, new-operator

I am attempting to use bubble sort in C++ which I am new to. This is my code so far:

My issue is that when ever I try and sort the arrays, the integer array is set to zero at every index.

Could this have something to do with memory allocation?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    //requires users input to create an array that wouldn't use too much memory
    cout << "Enter number of dealers you wish to enter" << endl;
    int array_size;
    cin >> array_size;
    std::string sales_names[array_size]; //makes a 2D array that can have 15 rows and 2 colums {Name, sales total}
    int sales_data[array_size];

    for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++){
        std::string dealers_name;
        int dealers_value;
        cout << "Enter Dealers Name: ";
        cin >> dealers_name;
        cin.clear();
        cout << "Enter Dealers Sales: ";
        cin >> dealers_value;
        sales_names[i] = dealers_name;
        sales_data[i] = dealers_value;
        cout << endl;
    }

    string temp_name;
    int temp_value;

    //Bubble Sort?
    for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++){
        for(int k = 0; k < array_size; k++){
            if(sales_data[k] = sales_data[k+1])
            {
                temp_value = sales_data[k];
                temp_name = sales_names[k];

                sales_data[k] = sales_data[k+1];
                sales_names[k] = sales_names[k+1];

                sales_data[k+1] = temp_value;
                sales_names[k+1] = temp_name;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++){
        cout << sales_data[i] << endl;
        cout << sales_names[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Im not sure why, but after the first loop of the for loop, every item in the sales_data array is set to 0

Here is my output:

```
Enter number of dealers you wish to enter
3
Enter Dealers Name:test1
 Enter Dealers Sales:12

Enter Dealers Name:test2
 Enter Dealers Sales:6

Enter Dealers Name:test3
 Enter Dealers Sales:9

0
test3
0
test2
0
test1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you are missing includes, and `std::string sales_names[array_size];` is a variable lenght array which is not standard c++, use `std::vector` when you need a dynamically sized array

Comment: btw `//makes a 2D array that can have 15 rows and 2 colums` I dont like comments, becuase typically they are liars, this is no exception. Perhaps it was left over after changing the code, in any case there is no 2d array of size 15x2 in your code

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I would love to use vectors, but we've been challenged not to use vectors.

Comment: in that case you have to dynamically allocate memory for the array.

Comment: Change `if(sales_data[k] = sales_data[k+1])` to `if(sales_data[k] == sales_data[k+1])`, and stop your loops before `k`, if you want to look at `k + 1`

Comment: *but we've been challenged not to use vectors.* -- But you weren't told that the syntax you're using was invalid by your teacher?  And I guess the reason is that vectors make things "easier"?  Well if that's the reasoning, then variable length arrays would make things super-easy.  Bottom line, the code you produced is not C++.

Comment: @doctorlove Thanks! I can't believe I missed that!

Comment: @HarveyJarvis It's easier to spot such tiny things when you enable warnings in your compiler. This helpful beast can definitely spot mistaking `=` for `==` for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison is wrong:

```
if (sales_data[k] = sales_data[k + 1])
```

This should be a `<` (or a `>`, depending on if you want to sort ascending or descending). Even if you wanted to test for equality, `==` would have been right, not `=`. Also here

```
for (int k = 0; k < array_size-1; k++) {
```

You should put `array_size-1`, otherwise it's going out of bounds.

Also note that VLAs aren't actually part of standard C++. Use `std::vector` instead:

```
std::vector<std::string> sales_names(array_size);
std::vector<int> sales_data(array_size);
```

By the way, that comment about it making a 2D array is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You have two obvious problems.

In

```
for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++){
    for(int k = 0; k < array_size; k++){
        if(sales_data[k] = sales_data[k+1])
```

you are assigning (`=`) instead of comparing (`==`). Though there's no point in a bubble if they match. Perhaps you want less than?

Also, watch out for running up to `k`, and inspecting `k+1`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with your code:

- `sales_data[k] = sales_data[k+1]` should be `sales_data[k] == sales_data[k+1]`
- `for(int k = 0; k < array_size; k++)` loop should start from `i+1` for a bubble sort or you can change the condition to `k < array_size-i-1`

Answer (score 0):

2 changes/questions:

1. Why are you swapping when data is same ? You only need to swap if i < k and      arr[i] > arr[k].
2. You are going out of bounds when accessing k+1 for inner loop, it should be     k

.